# How to get Image file size in django model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I wanna save image file size in database after uploading it. How can I do that in django models? It'll also work if I can get the size in the views. But since there can be multiple images in one Community post, I am unable to get the size for each of them.
My models.py file:

```py
from django.db import models
import os


class Community(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title


class CommunityImages(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Community, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    height = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    width = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='communityImages/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True, height_field='height', width_field='width')
    @property
    def images_exists(self):
        return self.communityImages.storage.exists(self.communityImages.name)
    def community(self):
        return self.post.id
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s " % (self.post_id, self.image, )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Community Images"
```

My views.py file:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import CommunityImages, Community
import json
import os


def image_detail(request, post_id):
    community_post = {}
    communityPostImages = list(CommunityImages.objects.filter(post=post_id).values('id','image', 'height', 'width'))
    
    for i in range(len(communityPostImages)):
        communityPostImages[i]['img_name'] = os.path.split(communityPostImages[i]['image'])[-1]
        communityPostImages[i]['type'] = os.path.splitext(communityPostImages[i]['img_name'])[-1].replace('.', '')
        communityPostImages[i]['dimension'] = str(communityPostImages[i]['height']) + "x" + str(communityPostImages[i]['width'])

    community_post['communityPostImages'] = communityPostImages
    data = json.dumps(community_post, indent=4, sort_keys=False, default=str)
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain this with the [**`.size`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.size) attribute of the `FieldFile` that is stored in the `FileField`:

> The result of the underlying `Storage.size()` method.

The [**`Storage.size(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.size) will:

> **Returns the total size, in bytes**, of the file referenced by name. For storage systems that aren’t able to return the file size this will raise `NotImplementedError` instead.

Here you thus can obtain the size of the file with:

```
some_community_image.image.size  # size in bytes
```

Comment: I know that. But I wonder if I could do that keeping the ImageField. Thank you

Comment: @Zubayer: this also works for an `ImageField`, since an `ImageField` is a subclass of a `FileField`, so everything that can be done with a `FileField`, can be done with an `ImageField`.