# WinError 2 The system cannot find the file specified:

Tags: python, django, sqlite, pdf, model

I have Django code which uploads pdf files to the SQLite database. In the first program, I uploaded successfully into the database but now I added some code and it shows me the error. The code i added is getting the size of the  file and saving it to the database

my code:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
import os

class BookUploadModel(models.Model):
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cover_page= models.ImageField()
    Book_file = models.FileField()
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price= models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(5)])
    published_date = models.DateField()
    file_size = models.BigIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.Book_file:
            self.file_size = os.path.getsize(self.Book_file.path)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
         verbose_name_plural = 'Books'
    def __str__(self):
         return f"Book ({self.id})"
    def clean_photo(self):
        image_file = self.cleaned_data.get('cover_page')
        if not image_file.cover_page.endswith(".jpg"):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Only .jpg image accepted")
        return image_file
```

views.py file:

```
def upload(request):
    form = UploadForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        # POST, return form with data from the request
        form = UploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():   
           form.save()
           form = UploadForm()
           return render(request,"upload.html",{'form':form})
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tade\.virtualenvs\djangosetup-z2E8Qdx0\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Tade\.virtualenvs\djangosetup-z2E8Qdx0\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tade\Desktop\djangosetup\bookstore_app\views.py", line 44, in upload
    form.save()
  File "C:\Users\Tade\.virtualenvs\djangosetup-z2E8Qdx0\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 542, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "C:\Users\Tade\Desktop\djangosetup\bookstore_app\models.py", line 17, in save
    self.file_size = os.path.getsize(self.Book_file.path)
  File "c:\users\tade\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size

Exception Type: FileNotFoundError at /upload
Exception Value: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\Tade\\Desktop\\djangosetup\\20210303_083652.jpg'
```

so, when i try to upload the file, i face the above problem.

Comment: Has the file been saved?   Are you supposed to call ```super().save(*args, **kwargs)``` first then do the check?  With your current code,  the file hasn't been saved and therefore,  filename can't be found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Image file size in django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68044057/how-to-get-image-file-size-in-django-model)

Comment: Please post your `upload.html`

Comment: it helped me a lot. I changed self.file_size = self.Book_file.size